# SocketTimeoutException in Retrofit when slow internet connection

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have error SocketTimeoutException in Retrofit when slow internet connection.

How can i handle this error?

This is my code:

```
val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com").client(okHttpClient).build()

val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        val response = service.getCoordinatesByCityName(city,"API", lang)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
            val prettyJson = gson.toJson(JsonParser.parseString(response.body()?.string()))
            val jsonData = Gson().fromJson(prettyJson, CityJson::class.java)

            val lat = jsonData.results[0].geometry.location.lat
            val lng = jsonData.results[0].geometry.location.lng
                                           
            Log.d("TAG", lat.toString())         
        }
    } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
        Log.d("TAG", "ERROR")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the method `clone` on your retrofit instance. With the new one you can again call the service (after showing them to retry after first call).

Comment: I can't, because app crashes when doesn't get response

Comment: Put the part I said in the catch part does not help you?

Comment: I don't need call service again, i just want to show Toast user, but app crushes

Comment: You should check more about the problem in the stack trace, where in the code does it cause the crash and detail about it. I can't help you further with this little information